# How do I avoid an application crash from a SecurityError when using Firebase Performance Monitoring?

Tags: firebase, angularfire2

I'm using Angular with angular/fire and having issues with the Performance Module.

Our application needs to work within an Iframe (part of a business strategy we have not been able to change yet).

When a user visits the website hosting the Iframe from Safari the application crashes with a `SecurityError`.

```
Unhandled Promise rejection: IDBFactory.open() called in an invalid security context
```

I've tried dynamically importing the AngularPerformaneModule only once I've detected that we were in an environment where IDBFactory worked.

I've tried switching out all of IDBFactory with a fake using fake-indexeddb.

So far, neither of those solutions have worked.

If anyone has any ideas as to how to handle this situation it would be much appreciated.

For the solution, it's acceptable for the performance module to not operate within an Iframe (or when the IDBFactory is not available). There are other contexts when gathering metrics is possible that I can count on.

Comment: Suggest filing a bug against the AngularFire repo. That's probably the best way to explore this, but it sounds like an unsupported scenario.

Comment: Alright, added the issue here: https://github.com/angular/angularfire2/issues/2134